# Returns exception "Expression cannot contain lambda expressions" when getting XML document using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, lambda

I want to get an XElement using linq from XML Document.

My linq query is:

```
webDetails.Descendants("WebApplications")
          .Descendants("WebApplication")
          .Where(x => x.Attribute("Uri").Value.Equals(selectedItem.Value))
          .FirstOrDefault();
```

The file contains following xml nodes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<WebApplications>
  <WebApplication Name="SharePoint - 80" Uri="http://xxxx/">
    <SiteCollections>
      <SiteCollection>
        <RootWeb Title="Root" Url="/">
          <Webs />
        </RootWeb>
      </SiteCollection>
      <SiteCollection>
        <RootWeb Title="My Site Host" Url="/my/HostSite">
          <Webs />
        </RootWeb>
      </SiteCollection>
    </SiteCollections>
  </WebApplication>
  <WebApplication Name="SharePoint - 9999" Uri="http://xxx/">
    <SiteCollections>   
        <SiteCollection>
        <RootWeb Title="Ritesh Goswami" Url="/my/rami">
          <Webs />
        </RootWeb>
      </SiteCollection>
      <SiteCollection>
        <RootWeb Title="Riyaz Kalva" Url="/my/rialva">
          <Webs />
        </RootWeb>
      </SiteCollection>
    </SiteCollections>
  </WebApplication>
</WebApplications>
```

If I execute query like :

```
webDetails.Descendants("WebApplications").Descendants("WebApplication").First()
```

I am getting first element but when I filter using attribute value I am getting above mentioned error. 
What should I do to filter xmlelement using attribute value?

Comment: Please post the *exact* error message. The code looks okay to me.

Comment: And in a small test app, this compiles with no problems. (I'd personally use `doc.Root.Elements("WebApplication").FirstOrDefault(x => (string) x.Attribute("Uri") == selectedItem.Value)` but that's a different matter.

Comment: Also please give more context - if this is an *exception*, how are you using the query? Ideally, post a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I tried your code and it works, the xml was in a bad format just fixed that and I got the second element with the filter

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
webDetails.Descendants("WebApplications").Descendants("WebApplication").Where(x => string.Equals(x.Attribute("Uri").Value, selectedItem.Value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
string s = selectedItem.Value;
webDetails.Descendants("WebApplications").Descendants("WebApplication").Where(x => x.Attribute("Uri").Value.Equals(s)).FirstOrDefault();
```